# Standard deviation of a discrete Gaussian filter

Tags: matlab, gaussian, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

I created a Gaussian filter in MATLAB as shown below:

```
 f = fspecial('gaussian', [1, 3], 2);
```

This created a 1-by-3 filter with a Gaussian distribution. However, when I do `std(f)`, I get a different value and not 2.

Why do I not get a value of 2 for the standard deviation?

Comment: How much different is it? I don't think you will ever get exactly 2.

Comment: For future visitors:  The [documentation for `fspecial()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/fspecial.html) says this isn't recommended and recommends using [`imgaussfilt()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imgaussfilt.html) or [`imgaussfilt3()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imgaussfilt3.html) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `f` is a sampling of the normal distribution. Its values are not normally distributed. Its 2nd order spatial central moment should be 4 (square of sigma value), but the standard deviation of the samples will not.
(Contrast sampling the distribution itself to sampling random values with a given distribution, the latter would have `std(f)` close to the standard deviation of the distribution).

The 2nd order central moment can be computed as follows:

```matlab
x = 1:numel(f);
m1 = sum(x.*f)/sum(f);         % 1st order moment
m2 = sum((x-m1).^2.*f)/sum(f); % 2nd order central moment
```

Nonetheless, if you plot your sampled `f`, you'll see it's not like a Gaussian at all! This is because it is cut off, the three points you sampled are all clustered close to the peak, and there's no samples in the tail. You need to sample a larger region. I always recommend sampling out to 3*sigma on each side:

```matlab
sigma = 2;
sz = ceil(3*sigma) * 2 + 1;
f = fspecial('gaussian', [1, sz], sigma)
```

See [my blog post on sampling the Gaussian kernel](https://www.crisluengo.net/archives/695).